# how to maintain order of namespaces in soap response envelop

Tags: java, spring-boot, dom, soap

I am working on a SOAP based web services and moved the old code to spring boot based project.
There are few namespaces required in SOAP response which are being added through EndpointInterceptor but it does not maintain the order of attributes (namespaces) being added in SOAP-ENV:Envelope.

For example, below is the current output

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”
xmlns:item=“http://MY_NAMESPACE.com/”
xmlns:s=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”
xmlns:soapenv=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”
xmlns:xsd=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”
xmlns:xsi=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

whereas SOAP service clients expect to have the below order for attributes define for the envelop

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”
xmlns:xsi=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xmlns:xsd=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”
xmlns:item=“http://MY_NAMESPACE.com/”
xmlns:soapenv=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”
xmlns:s=“http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: The order shouldn't matter to the receiver.

Comment: Ideally yes, but an issue is reported to maintain order. There seems to be an old version which requires namespaces to be in order.